# How to find $x$ for $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}x^{\frac{3}{2}}}=-\frac{1}{4}e^{-\frac{x}{4}}\left(A-B\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function, lambert-w

The title pretty much explains it; I've had trouble with this because when taking the logarithm of both sides $x$ can never be isolated. I have been looking into the Lambert W function, but I've never applied it before and don't know whether it can solve for $x$ in this instance. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Both are constants which, along with $x$, are in the set of real numbers

Comment: Without the value of $A$ and $B$, $x$ won't be unique.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to isolate $x$ and find a function of $A$ and $B$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}$

\begin{align} 
-\frac1{\sqrt2 x^{\tfrac32}}
&=-\frac14 \exp(-\tfrac x4)(A-B)
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
-x^{-\tfrac32}
&=-\frac{\sqrt2}4(A-B)\exp(-\tfrac x4)
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Let $\frac{\sqrt2}4(A-B)=1/c$,
then we have

\begin{align} 
c
&=
x^{\tfrac32}\exp(-\tfrac x4)
\tag{3a}\label{3a}
,\\
c^{\tfrac23}
&=
x\exp(-\tfrac x4\cdot \tfrac23)
=x\exp(-\tfrac x6)
\tag{3b}\label{3b}
,\\
-\tfrac16\,c^{\tfrac23}
&=x\exp(-\tfrac x4\cdot \tfrac23)
=-\tfrac16x\exp(-\tfrac 16\,x)
\tag{4}\label{4}
,\\
-\tfrac16x\exp(-\tfrac 16\,x)
&=
-\tfrac16\,c^{\tfrac23}
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
\W\left(-\tfrac16x\exp(-\tfrac 16\,x)\right)
&=
\W\left(-\tfrac16\,c^{\tfrac23}\right)
\tag{6}\label{6}
,\\
-\tfrac16x
&=
\W\left(-\tfrac16\,c^{\tfrac23}\right)
\tag{7}\label{7}
,\\
x
&=
-6
\W\left(-\tfrac16\,c^{\tfrac23}\right)
\tag{8}\label{8}
,\\
x
&=
-6
\W\left(-\tfrac13\,(A-B)^{-\tfrac23}\right)
\tag{9}\label{9}
.
\end{align}

The number of the real solutions is defined
by
$z=-\tfrac13\,(A-B)^{-\tfrac23}$,
the argument of $\W$:

\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
z\ge0:\quad &\text{ one real solution, }\quad x=-6\Wp(z),\quad x\le0
,\\
z\in(-\tfrac1\e,0):\quad &\text{ two real solutions, }\quad x_0=-6\Wp(z),\ x_1=-6\Wm(z),\quad 0<x_0<x_1
,\\
z=-\tfrac1\e:\quad &\text{ one real solution, }\quad x=-6\Wp(-\tfrac1\e)=-6\Wm(-\tfrac1\e)=-1
,\\
z<-\tfrac1\e:\quad &\text{ no real solutions}
,
\end{cases}
\end{align}

where $\Wp$ is the principal branch
and $\Wm$ is the other real branch
of the Lambert $\W$ function.

Note that above cases describe the number of solutions in a general case of $\W(z)$,
in case of this particular equation \eqref{1}, both $x$ and $A-B$ must be positive,
so $z\ge0$ is not an option.

Also, minimum valid difference $A-B$ is reached at $x=6$:
\begin{align}
\min (A-B)
&=
\tfrac{\sqrt3}9\,\exp(\tfrac32)\approx 0.86250
.
\end{align}

Example in `python`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import lambertw as W

def flhs(x,a_b):
  return -1/np.sqrt(2)*np.power(x,-3/2)

def frhs(x,a_b):
  return -a_b/4*np.exp(-x/4)

A_B=0.9
z=-1/3*(np.power(A_B,-2/3))

print(z)
# -0.35758866096504804

x0=-6*W(z).real
x1=-6*W(z,-1).real

print(x0,x1)
# 4.68190384793268 7.544928735449594

# check:

print(flhs(x0,A_B), frhs(x0,A_B))
# -0.06979933204881004 -0.06979933204881006

print(flhs(x1,A_B), frhs(x1,A_B))
# -0.0341194709980176 -0.034119470998017605
```

$\endgroup$

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much.